# I need a litle help about fsockopen function

Tags: php, authentication, fsockopen

I need a little help with the `fsockopen` function.

I have this PHP code:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554,47830,50070))
    || @fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 1))
```

I need to make `fsockopen` check IPs by port 80 if it doesn't request authentication.

I think I should use `isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])` in there somewhere, but I can't do it by myself. Can anyone help?

Update...........................

@drew010 Thank you very much

My Best Regards

Comment: You are much, much, much better off not putting that stuff within the actual `if` condition.

Comment: What's with the `@`? Wouldn't removing that give you valuable information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if the remote server requests authentication, you need to make a request and read the response.

If the response is 401 Authorization Required, then it is requesting auth, otherwise it is not.

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554,47830,50070)) {
    $fp = @fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 1);

    if ($fp) {
        $url = "/";

        fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
        $resp = '';

        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $resp .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }

        if (preg_match('/^http\/1\.\d+ 401/i', $resp)) {
            echo "Requires authentication";
        } else {
            echo "No auth required.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Failed to connect on port 80, reason: $errstr";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much You are right and you are so close....please wait a minute and read my updates

Comment: You're welcome, is there some part that isn't working or what can I do to help more?

Comment: yes..please could you check my Q again..i have updated it for you..thanks again

Comment: Ok so what exactly do you want to do, add another bit of information showing if it requires auth or not?

Comment: Everything is ok...Thank you very much drew010 and have a nice day !